# Call Sproc that returns an integer in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have seen great examples on how to call SQL in EF Core.  But all of them assume you have a custom type you want to deserialize into.

Basically, I am looking for a conversion of this full Dot Net Framework code that calls a sproc to get an integer:

```
 int newId = this.Database.SqlQuery<int>("Order.GenerateOrderId").First();
```

Is there a way to call a Stored Procedure that just returns an integer using Entity Framework Core?